# Are there any hostels in Dubai?

Tags: hostels, dubai

I'm searching for hostels in Dubai. And I only can find one hostel: “EasyFlat 12 Dubai Hostel“.

Are there any other hostels in Dubai?

I will travel solo so I don't want to stay in a hotel.

Comment: Thank you pnuts. I checked hostelworld and all of them are hotels not hostels. Except the one I mention before. :-(

Comment: As I can remember there are just a couple but are outside of the city. Just get a cheap hotel. Check sites like booking.com or walk in the Deira zone and ask at receptions.

Comment: I haven't stayed in Dubai for more than a few hours, so I probably didn't research well. But as surprising as this sounds for a city with a lot of hotels and economy, I couldn't find any single hostel from booking.com not by asking from locals. You'd have to get a cheap hotel room as @Majed suggested.

Comment: Thank u alessandro. But I don't like to stay in hotels if I'm solo.

Comment: Ayesh  I found something in airbnb. But it not a real hostel. Although there is alot of good bnb in dubai but not hostels

Comment: Can you explain your comment: "I will travel solo so I don't want to stay in a hotel."? Why would travelling by yourself prevent you from staying in a hotel? Probably most hotel rooms worldwide are occupied by solo travellers.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier I travel solo and also don't want to stay in a hotel. It's not that it prevents us, it's that hostels are far more social, and you can meet and travel with people you meet there. Otherwise you're alone in a hotel room :/

Comment: I would argue that's what the bar is for ;) But sure, OK, understood now. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

HiHostels has not one, but two hostels in Dubai.

They're not terribly imaginatively named, but:

- [Dubai - A](https://www.hihostels.com/hostels/dubai-a)
- [Dubai - B](https://www.hihostels.com/hostels/dubai-b)

You don't need to be an HI member to stay there, but you do get a discount if you are one.

Comment: That sound great :) thank you. You deserve more than +1

Comment: We will accept it alter .. I hope to find more hostels :)